# Handbrake Advanced tab showing no options

Tags: json

Handbrake 0.10.5.0 activated advanced tab, but it is not showing any options under it. MP4 file is loaded and MP4 is selected for output.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both the preference and the "Use Advanced Tab"  checkbox that is located on the "Video" tab on the main window checked for the Advanced tab to become available. Note, it's only available for the x264 encoder.